# Accessing my computer from the office

Tags: remote-desktop

I would like to be able to access my home computer from my office, not just through SSH but full Desktop interface.

I face several challenges here:

- Setting up a Virtual Desktop (Something like VNC? I hear that it doesnt work with Unity)
- Setting up port forwarding on the home router (I am not even sure if I really have to do this)
- Setting some sort of domain, as I will not be able to predict the IP address (I already own my own domain, so I should be able to use something like "home.mydomain.com", but Im not sure how)

Can someone give me a tutorial, detailed as possible, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). It is commercial software free for personal use. I'm not sure if connecting to your office will qualify as personal.

If you want a free (both meanings) way, I will try to give some general guidelines. You should probably ask one question for each problem for a complete answer (some are already answered in this site, IIRC):

1. You can use Desktop Sharing to set up VNC for you. It is already bundled in Ubuntu so just search for it in the dash and activate it. It will not create a virtual desktop but share your real one.
2. You'll need to forward at least port 5900 in your router. You should seek advice for your router model, as each different router have a different interface.
3. You will need to set up a Dynamic DNS to be able to do this. Most routers support this, so check this first as configuring it at router level is usually better. If you router doesn't support dynamic dns you can do it from Ubuntu.

Comment: an slternate is FreeNX, also fast, safe, secure ...

Comment: Yes, it's quite hard to configure but really powerful. I had used it in the past to allow more than 15 users to open remote sessions over ADSL.

Comment: @Javier Rivera : He wants to connect *to* home *from* the office, so that's personal.  http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/213-How-exactly-is-private-use-defined.aspx

Comment: And thanks for mentioning FreeNX. never heard about it.